# Is this document describing pedophile logos an authentic FBI document?

Tags: united-states, criminology, document-authenticity

This [WFTV report](http://www.wftv.com/news/national-content/symbol-for-pedophiles-seems-to-appear-on-childrens-toys-sold-at-monster-jam/155556144) references an FBI document:

> A symbol purportedly called the "GirlLover logo" found on FBI
>   documents from 2007 looks similar to the symbol O’Kelly found on the
>   toy she bought.
>
> According to the documents, the logo symbolizes a relationship between
>   an adult and a minor girl.

The referenced [FBI document](http://senado.pr.gov/Ponencias/ps%20734%20Policia%20de%20Puerto%20Rico%20Anejo.pdf) doesn't seem authentic, and sources Wikipedia.

Is this a genuine FBI document?

Comment: Euhhh. This logo was found in the FBI Document you linked. If that evidence doesn't convince, nothing will. -1.

Comment: Seems a bit strange for the "FBI document" to be using Wikipedia as their authoritative reference... that said, it seems some websites may actually be using that symbol, whether it originated with them or if they adopted it having seen others note it as an "official" symbol.

Comment: What's the claim here? 1) Is this symbol used to symbolize adults and minor girls? 2) Does the pattern on the monster truck toy look like that symbol? [Off-topic - Opinion] 3) Was the logo on the meant to look like it? [Off-topic - Motivation]

Comment: @Oddthinking I worded it poorly. "Is the document authentic?"

Comment: @Raystafarian: I've updated the question to match

Comment: "Looks similar to." - that's an awfully broad net.  If the logo isn't "identical to" or "almost completely identical to," then it's not the same.  So, "similar to" means nothing, and the source is really irrelevant.  This is a pretty famous tactic for conspiracy peddlers.  "Similar to" peddled with a strong injection of "equals the same" inference.

Comment: @Raystafarian - I'm more irritated with the people who make the inference than folks who ask about it.  Asking about it gives the opportunity to point out that technique for those who haven't seen it in action before.  No downvote from here.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet sorry, I read (and reacted) incorrectly to your statement.

Comment: @Raystafarian - it was a very broadly critical statement, and very open to many interpretations.  No need to apologize for my lack of disclaimers, explanation or qualifications.  Have a good one!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you noted, the information does seem to be part of an "FBI document" sent to law enforcement, albeit one that quotes Wikipedia as a source. That said, there's no proof yet that this is an official document, or correct. Take, for example, the infamous [Blue Star tattoo](http://www.lycaeum.org/drugs/other/tattoo/) memo, which claims that there's a growing issue with people trying to "hook" kids on LSD by impregnating tattoos with cartoon characters with acid.

Also, answering the question in your title, the symbol might have been an unintentional similarity. [Unilever](http://www.ola.nl/) uses a very similar symbol and have for many years.

[image: Unilever logo]

Just for the sake of completeness, Snopes ran [an article about the situation](http://www.snopes.com/code-for-pedophiles-on-toys/) and their verdict was that there's some similarity, but a) there's no indication that it was intentional (and they point out other similar symbols) and b) it's not likely to harm a child in any way to be exposed to said symbol, particularly since the majority of child sexual assaults are by friends and family, not by strangers.

Comment: Thanks for reading my poorly worded question the way I intended it to be read.